# Negative number passed to function with uint parameter

Tags: solidity

Consider the following simple contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract TestContract {

    function add(uint256 amount) returns (uint256) {
       require(amount > 0);

       return 100 + amount;
    }
}
```

I would expect that the result of this function is always greater than 100. Except for an uint overflow scenario, but let's not discuss that.

If i call the function from geth like this the result is like expected 105.

```
> testInstance.add.call(5)
```

If i call the function with an negative number, i would expect that an exception is thrown or that the input is changed to zero and the result is 100, but instead in returns 95.

```
> testInstance.add.call(-5)
```

So how is that possible? Has anyone an idea? Is it just bad practice to pass negative numbers to the function?

Comment: If you change uint256 to int256 it will work as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe this is exactly the integer overflow you mentioned.

I agree that on the `web3` side, passing a negative number should probably be treated as an error. But on the Solidity side, I assume what your function receives is a 32-byte representation of the two's complement value for -5 (a really big number). When added to 100, taking into account integer overflow, the result is 95.

Comment: I guess you're right, it's the integer overflow. If i just return the input parameter, i can see that it is a very big number. Thank you for the fast answer!

Answer (score 7):

I just wanted to add the reason **why there is no exception raised**.
[In Solidity Issues on GitHub](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/533#issuecomment-218776352) the similar question was raised. And here is the answer:

> Forget about two's complement, this is just how it is represented
>   internally, but the math should work out even without having to think
>   about two's complement. Here is how it works:
>
> Operations on variables of `uint` are performed in the ring mod 2^256.
>   Furthermore, if **x** and **y** are `uint` variables, then certainly something
>   like **x-y** should be possible (and is just computed mod 2^256). Since
>   **-a** is just a short hand for **0-a**, I don't see why it should be disallowed. Since 0 is equivalent to 2^256, is is just natural that
>   -1 is the same as 2^256-1, which is 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.

*By the way. I tried your code in remix, and remix is constantly throwing error about passing negative numbers to uint variables even before it goes to `require` function.*