# ERC20 example contract: Is _amount > 0 check necessary?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

[Ethereum wiki](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) shows this example function:

```
14     // Transfer the balance from owner's account to another account
15     function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) returns (bool success) {
16         if (balances[msg.sender] >= _amount 
17             && _amount > 0
18             && balances[_to] + _amount > balances[_to]) {
19             balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
20             balances[_to] += _amount;
21             return true;
22         } else {
23             return false;
24         }
25     }
```

Notice that there are two checks here: `_amount > 0` and `balances[_to] + _amount > balances[_to]`. I understand these two are for preventing [the integer overflow attack](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33832/negative-number-passed-to-function-with-uint-parameter).

But isn't the `balances[_to] + _amount > balances[_to]` check enough? Can we remove the `_amount > 0` check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it is not necessary. If you're worried about a spam of meaningless transfer events, it doesn't help at all because someone can just transfer `0.000000001` tokens many times.

Returning `false` on a transfer of 0 tokens is a very bad idea. One of the most important features of the EVM is that contracts can call functions in other contracts. If a contract calls `transfer` on a token contract with a dynamically calculated amount of tokens, it might sometimes transfer `0`. If the token contract then returns false, the calling contract will think the transfer failed, even though nothing was wrong.

I would do this:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) returns (bool success) {
    if (_amount == 0) return true;
    // Rest of the transfer function...
```

That way `transfer` calls with `_amount == 0` will succeed, and use as little gas as possible.

Comment: `use as little gas as possible.` +1

Answer (score 2):

`_amount > 0` is there to prevent people from transferring 0 tokens. 
If you take it out, a function call with 0 tokens will not fail but not do anything, except consuming all the gas provided and used as well as firing an event (if you had it) recording a Transfer of 0 tokens.

Comment: `balances[_to] + _amount > balances[_to]` already can handle this 0-value scenario. `_amount > 0` is not necessary and adds gas costs. Agree?

Comment: You are right, my bad.